# Using Byobu, how do you split the screen when using PuTTY?

Tags: byobu, putty

When running Byobu, how do you split the screen when using PuTTY?

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> just prints a character in the terminal.

Comment: related to: http://askubuntu.com/questions/493082/how-to-split-byobu-screen

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know this is an old question - but in case you did not get any answer....

I just started using Byobu with PuTTY, and found that I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>%</kbd> to split the screen vertically and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>|</kbd> to split the active pane horizontally.

These key commands are based on the screen program. You can find more at the [screen man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Regions).

Obviously <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is the prefix I'm using, change that to whatever prefix you are using.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Are there more commands that we can use with screen escaping? A link to a list of them would be great.

Comment: And Ctrl-A, Tab switched focus between splits.

Answer (score 1):

In my mapping, I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to move to beginning of line, and the escape char is <kbd>F12</kbd>. so it becomes:

<kbd>F12</kbd><kbd>%</kbd> to split vertically; and
<kbd>F12</kbd><kbd>|</kbd> (pipe <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>\</kbd>) to split horizontally