# How to split byobu screen?

Tags: byobu

On the `byobu` Wikipedia page there is a screenshot with the terminal screen:

[image: Link to terminal screen using byobu]

1. Can somebody explain to me what programs are used here?
   My guess - at the bottom - `vim`, top right - terminal, top left - I don't know.
2. And how to make such a byobu screen?

Comment: top left program is `htop`, a persistent version of `top`. It lists running processes and hardware load, and allows you to search processes, send them signals, ...

Comment: @Ploutox: `top` is also persistent :S

Comment: @andriusz Can you change the accepted answer?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The controls have changed since the accepted answer was posted. From [Byobu's help page:](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Byobu)

- Split screen horizontally:

  - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or
  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>|</kbd>
- Split screen vertically:

  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or
  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>%</kbd>
- Switch focus:

  - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑ ↓ ← →</kbd> or
  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>↑ ↓ ← →</kbd>

Comment: And how do we close one or more splits?

Comment: @Tarik type `exit` in split, which you want to close.

Comment: That's if you want to exit the terminal. If you want to stop splitting, then in the screen version `Ctrl-A` followed by `Q` will "maximize" the current window

Comment: If you use emacs key bindings.. then replace `Ctrl+A` with `F12`

Comment: Shift+F2 or Ctrl+F2?  You say both.  Does that mean "new pane"?

Comment: Actually it seems like `Ctrl+A` and then `|` is all that's needed to split the screen vertically?

Answer (score 27):

> 1 . Can somebody explain to me what programs are used here?

- Program top left is the command [`htop`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htop) (is similar to command `top`)
- Program top right is indeed a terminal and the bottom one is indeed `vim`

> 2 . And how to make such a `byobu` screen?

- Horizontal split: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd>
- Vertical split: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>|</kbd> (there is a vertical screen patch that switches the shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd>)
- To move the focus to the next split: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>

---

[Some more shortcuts](http://linuxaria.com/howto/screen-byobu?lang=en).

Comment: The shortcuts have changed since. See help.ubuntu.com/community/Byobu `Shift`+`F2` and `Ctrl`+`F2` split the screen horizontally and vertically respectively. Moving focus is done with `Shift`+`Arrow Key` (left, right, up, down) depending on the focus switch you want to do.

Comment: This is what works for me: `Ctrl` + `A` `%` to split horizontally and `Ctrl` + `A` `|` to split vertically.

Comment: Doesn't work with Emacs bindings. ;)

Comment: @A.B. Think of these commands as [prefix] + [command]. On my system, the default prefix for Emacs-compatibility is `C-S`. So, in my case, I press `C-S %` to split horizontally. (See comment by Hoang Huynh above.)

Comment: @HoangHuynh Strange, in my case your shortcuts work, but do the exact opposite.

Comment: If you use emacs key bindings.. then replace Ctrl+A with F12